# Numpy 3d array map operation

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Now I have a 3-dimension np.array [height, weight, 3]. (It is a image) And I want to implement an RGB -> YUV algorithm myself [RGB2YUV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzKTZ.png). However, iterating from each pixel and applying the transform is too slow.

```
for x in xrange(height):
    for y in xrange(weight):
          img[x,y] = mat_1 * img[x,y]
```

Is there any way to use some built_in method implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good use-case for [np.einsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
yuv_image = np.einsum('kl,ijl->ijk', transformation_matrix, rgb_image)
```

It's easy to come up with the indices, once you've written it down on a piece of paper.

Example to show value equality of both approaches:

```
>>> rgb_image = np.random.rand(2*4*3).reshape(2,4,3)
>>> transformation_matrix = np.random.rand(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> z = np.empty_like(rgb_image)
>>> for x in range(rgb_image.shape[0]):
...     for y in range(rgb_image.shape[1]):
...         z[x,y] = np.dot(transformation_matrix, rgb_image[x,y,:])
...
>>> np.allclose(z, np.einsum('kl,ijl->ijk', transformation_matrix, rgb_image))
True
```